# Which Conditions Describe the Connection Between Poisson and Binomial Distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions

From binominal distribution if

1. $n\to\infty$,
2. $p\to 0$ and
3. $n\cdot p=\lambda$ where λ constant

then binominal approaches poisson distribution. How can I define in typical form the above three conditions?

Comment: Please, when asking a question try to avoid typos. The title is the very first thing people see of your question…

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you would say you have sequences $n_i\in\Bbb N$ and $p_i\in \Bbb R^+$ with

$$\lim_{i\to\infty} n_i=\infty,\qquad \lim_{i\to\infty} p_i=0, \qquad \lim_{i\to\infty} n_i p_i=\lambda$$

for some $\lambda \in\Bbb R$. To ensure that the third condition is always fulfilled you can exemplary choose

$$p_i:=\frac\lambda{n_i}.$$

In this case we always have $n_ip_i=\lambda$, and so this is also true in the limit.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain better the third condition?How can i define the two sequences so the product is constant? Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderGotses In this way? Or what do you want to know exactly?

Comment: I have seen that definition in some courses about probalities. The difficult part for me is the third condition. I can't understand how the product of the two sequences is constant. I i tried to define the sequences but i can not. Is it easy to define them ? If not can you point some source?? Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexanderGotses I am not quite sure what you mean by *defining* them. I gave you definitions or formalizations but you do not seem to be satisfied. An example of such a pair of sequences would be $n_i\equiv 1,2,3,4,5,...$ and $p_i\equiv 1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,...$. You see that $n_i\cdot p_i$ is always $1$, even though that $n$ is constantly increasing and $p$ is always decreasing.

Comment: Yes but as i remember and correct me if i'm wrong the product of ni *pi is not  λ  but is also a sequence . we define a third sequence λi wich is not a constant number . when n goes to infinity and p to zero then λi goes to λ.

Comment: @AlexanderGotses Ok. Always keep in mind that the *constant* sequence $\lambda,\lambda,\lambda,...$ is also a sequence with the obvious limit $\lambda$. But take this example: $n_i\equiv 1,2,3,...$ and $p_i\equiv \frac12,\frac13,\frac14,...$, then $\lambda_i=n_i p_i\equiv \frac12,\frac23,\frac 34,...$ which will converge to $\lambda=1$.

Comment: The example is not successful as the product is a constant. Any source would be very helpful for me. The common books of probabilities i have assume the sequences. Thanks again .

Comment: @AlexanderGotses I honestly have no idea what you are asking about exactly. All I can do is pointing you [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem). However, in my last example the product is *no* constant at all but depends on $i$.

Comment: Sorry i dint saw the last change you made. So if i want  λ> 1 i just multiply the n sequence with λ. Thanks a lot .